# Jquery exception detected in Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, exception

this is the message error throwed for the chrome browser, and it works very well in IExplorer and FireFox

```
$ XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Lew/Documents/Human%20Staff/students.xml. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

.... I dont know why it doesnt work if already defined the variables...

another error mesagge throwed by the developer tool by chrome:

```
$nombre: [Exception: ReferenceError: telefono is not defined]
$edad : [Exception: ReferenceError: telefono is not defined]
$telefono : [Exception: ReferenceError: telefono is not defined]
$carnet : [Exception: ReferenceError: telefono is not defined]
```

any idea to fixed?

This is a code snipped:

```
<pre><code>

    // JavaScript Document
    // File: leerXML.js


   $(document).ready(function(){


   $("#ContentArea").ready(function(){
   $.get("students.xml",{},function(xml){ //Abrimos el archivo students.xml

// Crearemos un string HTML
    HTMLcontent = '<br/><br/>';
    HTMLcontent += '<table width="70%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
    HTMLcontent += '<th>Nombre</th><th>Edad</th><th>Telefono</th><th>Carnet</th>';

   $('estudiante',xml).each(function(i) {

   var nombre ='';
   var edad='';
   var telefono='';
   var carnet='';
   nombre = $(this).find("nombre").text(); 
   edad = $(this).find("edade").text();
   telefono = $(this).find("telefono").text();
   carnet = $(this).find("carnet").text();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this because you're loading the website from a local filesystem.  You need to run a web server in order to cross-origin request (the filesystem has an origin of null because it has no domain, and that is never permitted to make a cross origin request).

Set up a tiny web server and serve your files from that in order to test.  See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787.

Comment: Hi Hach-Que. So, I should suppose that if I upload my website on hosting it should works without problems?

Comment: Yes, or alternatively you can use a tiny web server like http://en.kioskea.net/faq/2568-tinyweb-server-on-windows.